# install/update/remove bundle programmatically

Tags: service, osgi, bundle, declarative

I'm new to osgi and wonder if it is possible to have a centralized mechanism to update, install or remove bundles.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I have downvoted your question because it does not show any research-effort. When asking questions in the future, please describe what you have already tried/found. The more specific your question is the more likely you are to get help (and he more likely it is that your question helps others with the same problem).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can do this programmatically, which means there are a large number of bundles that provide you out-of-the-box solutions. It is so easy (and so much fun) that for many people one of their first bundles is a little "management agent" (as the OSGi specification calls this part).

The absolute simplest solution is [Apache File Install](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-file-install.html). It tracks a directory and installs/uninstalls from there. Couple this to Google Drive or Dropbox and you have a large scale fully automated deploy model (it also handles configuration, which is quite important).

The OSGi specification now has an OSGi Bundle Repository (OBR) specification. This is a very powerful model to describe dependencies (not just bundles) that allow management agents to calculate/leverage dependencies. This is supported out of the box on Felix.

There are a myriad of solutions that manage OSGi frameworks. There is commercial support with Paremus, IBM Tivoli, ProSyst and many others. And open source with Apache ACE and fusebundles.

Comment: I have looked into fileinstall but I want to have the control over which bundle I want to install/uninstall or start/stop bundles. For ex. there are two new bundles that I need to install/update, but I just want to update one of them and postpone the other one later on. AS I understand FileInstall install/update bundles as soon as they arrive to the destination folder.

Answer (score 2):

There are two general ways to do that: Have you application to 'pull' bundles from a repository hosting bundles and update itself, or have an external provisioning application 'push' bundles to your application.

For pull solutions I'd say there is:

- Eclipse P2 Used by the update manager of Eclipse. Mature, stable, but can be a bit tricky to get into, also I'm not sure if P2 works with other OSGi runtimes than Eclipse Equinox
- Apache Bundle Repository (OBR) A bit easier, and it's in the OSGi spec.

For push solutions I'd say have a look at Apache Ace, from your question I think that is closest to what you want to do.